# Want three arrays separately without foreach and index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and three arrays inside of it, I want to have those three arrays as separate arrays without any index.
I have to place it in a meta query there I need it exactly like that.

```
foreach( $skill_obj_arr as $skills_query ){

    $meta_query[] = array(

           'key' => 'cs_skills', 
           'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', $skills_query),  
           'compare' => 'LIKE' );
        }   

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($meta_query);
    echo "</pre>";


Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [key] => cs_skills
        [value] => :"content-writer";
        [compare] => LIKE
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [key] => cs_skills
        [value] => :"data-scientist";
        [compare] => LIKE
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [key] => cs_skills
        [value] => :"front-end-developer";
        [compare] => LIKE
    )
 )
```

This is how I want them to be in one variable, how is it possible.  ▼   ▼   ▼

```
Array
    (
        [key] => cs_skills
        [value] => :"content-writer";
        [compare] => LIKE
    )

Array
    (
        [key] => cs_skills
        [value] => :"data-scientist";
        [compare] => LIKE
    )

Array
    (
        [key] => cs_skills
        [value] => :"front-end-developer";
        [compare] => LIKE
    )
```

Comment: `This is how I want them to be in one variable`-> the first one is exactly what you want. So it's unclear what you are asking

Comment: the first one is with index and second one is without index, I want them to be without index

Comment: Nick, when you are trying to use multiple meta tags in single query then actually it's in the format what you have in the first-one, not the second one

Comment: This is not possible. You want to store multiple value inside of array. Why do you want it to store that way?

Comment: I know @AlivetoDie the problem is with the first array it generates query like that array([0]=>array[0]=>array([key]) this does not make correct query it should be array([0]=>array[key] this way it creates correct query and bring correct records I have tested it manually already.

Comment: You can just call $meta_query[0][key]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:-

```
$args = array('meta_query' => array()); //this is args array

$meta_query = [];
foreach( $skill_obj_arr as $skills_query ){

    $meta_query[] = array(
           'key' => 'cs_skills', 
           'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', $skills_query),  
           'compare' => 'LIKE' 
       );
}
$args['meta_query'] = array('relation' => 'OR',$meta_query); //assign all meta-tags array to the argument array

print_r($args);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/894282

Reference taken:- https://tommcfarlin.com/wp_query-and-multiple-meta-keys/

Output of the reference code:- https://eval.in/894281

Comment: @NickTaylor  glad to help you

Comment: and thanks for understanding my need, not everyone can